# How to set proxy in R ( ubuntu)

Tags: r, ubuntu, proxy, cran, bioconductor

Gaurav Pandey

I used the command

```
Sys.setenv(http_proxy="http://myusername:pswd@host:port")
```

and it worked at first.
But on restarting It in the Terminal it showed the following error.-

```
 cannot open: HTTP status was '407 Proxy Authentication Required
```

How to resolve this issue.Help,,,

Comment: probably a question for superuser.com?

Answer (score 4):

You set the environment for the process running R.  When the instance of R exits, the process goes away, and the environment is gone.

You cannot set the environment for a parent process.

Put these commands in `/etc/profile` or `~/.bash_profile` instead:

```
export http_proxy
http_proxy=http://myusername:pswd@host:port
```

Or all on one line (for `bash`):

```
export http_proxy=http://myusername:pswd@host:port
```

Or run the commands in the shell before starting `R`.